# getting this "Integrity constraint violation: " while creating custom option

Tags: magento2, custom-options, save

I have create custom module to create custom option with the reference of this "https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-options-programmatically-in-magento-2/" page.

I'm getting bellow error for this "`$option->save();`" method.

> a:4:{i:0;s:277:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry '0-0' for key
>   'CATALOG_PRODUCT_OPTION_TYPE_PRICE_OPTION_TYPE_ID_STORE_ID', query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_option_type_price`
>   (`option_type_id`, `store_id`, `price`, `price_type`) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
>   ?)";i:1;s:7500:"#0
>   /app/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95):

I have already try with reindex and FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, but still getting error.

Comment: Is there any extension or a fresh Magento version?

Comment: it's my custom plugin, i have upgrade magento version from 2.1.6  to 2.1.14 after that i'm getting error

Answer (score 0):

please remove **catalog_product_option_type_price**  backup table if you have

or if you have whole databse backup then this error will come

Comment: how can we remove core table.this is not proper answer

Comment: I am saying that if you have take backup i am not talking about original table

Comment: @RutveeSojitra ,  i can't delete that table as there are lost off data which is related to other products.

Comment: First you check that catalog_product_option_type_price  any backup or duplicate table exist there?
Then think about this case

I am not talking about original table... if you have duplicate of that table

Comment: @Rutvee, i have done as you suggest, now showing this error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`main`.`catalog_product_option`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_OPT_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ROW_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`row_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_option` (`product_id`, `type`, `is_require`, `sort_order`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:6317:"#0 /app/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: Try:
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
then do reindex
then try to run code and after executing code please do `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83427/discussion-between-jimit-bhavsar-and-rutvee-sojitra).